# How is the json schema is looks like to generate a swager client with nswag

Tags: swagger, jsonschema, nswag

Here is a tab on nswag:

[image]

So how it the schema should be looks like? Routes, definitions, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a JSON Schema then NSwag generates a Swagger spec with only the DTO types of the schema - you cannot define routes, etc. For this you have to use a Swagger spec.